# Testing hardware in computer that fails to POST

Tags: hardware-failure, laptop-repair, post, diagnostic

With a computer that powers on and runs its fan, but doesn't get any further, what would be useful troubleshooting steps and diagnostic equipment (if any)? It seems undamaged to look at, and the user denies dropping it or getting it wet.

This machine is a Fujitsu Amilo laptop, but I'm more interested in learning general hardware troubleshooting. I have already taken the hard drive out and rescued the data, and I don't think (and the user agrees) a basic computer from 2007 is any great loss. Which does mean I can safely practice on it!

Answer (score 0):

Making yourself a plug-in beeper from old components wouldn't be a bad start. Many motherboards don't have that speaker any more, so you can't hear the beep codes.

You can buy them, but really it's 30s with a soldering iron to make your own.

[image]

Next is know where it goes…

[image]